# Postgresql: Able to authenticate using psql but unable to backup with pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I have trouble backing up a PostgreSQL database. When I run the following command:

```
psql -d cdb -U "$(whoami)"
```

The result:

```
cdb=# \c
You are now connected to database "cdb" as user "gub".
```

So no problems with that. However when I run

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U "$(whoami)" -d cdb -w -C -F p -b -f /home/"$(whoami)"/cdb.sql
```

I get the following error message:

```
pg_dump: error: connection to database "cdb" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I have the following auth settings:

```
cdb=# select * from pg_hba_file_rules;
 line_number | type  |   database    | user_name  |  address  |                 netmask                 | auth_method | options | error 
-------------+-------+---------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------
          89 | local | {all}         | {postgres} |           |                                         | peer        |         | 
          94 | local | {all}         | {all}      |           |                                         | peer        |         | 
          96 | host  | {all}         | {all}      | 127.0.0.1 | 255.255.255.255                         | md5         |         | 
          98 | host  | {all}         | {all}      | ::1       | ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff | md5         |         | 
         101 | local | {replication} | {all}      |           |                                         | peer        |         | 
         102 | host  | {replication} | {all}      | 127.0.0.1 | 255.255.255.255                         | md5         |         | 
         103 | host  | {replication} | {all}      | ::1       | ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff | md5         |         |
```

I am not sure why this is not working as `auth_method peer` should not require a password. Can someone please help? postgresql.conf has not been changed and setup is: `psql (PostgreSQL) 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)`

My goal is to backup without the need of a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `psql`, you are using a local connection via domain sockets, since you didn't specify `-h localhost`, so the first or second `pg_hba.conf` line applies, and you can connect without a password.

With `pg_dump`, you are using a TCP connection, and the third or fourth line applies, and you have to supply a password.

Omit `-h localhost`!

Comment: Exellent. thanks so much Laurenz.